# Change CSS value when page has loaded?

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to change a value of a css style after the page has finished loading?

For example I need to change a division that is `display:block` to `display:none` after the page has finished loading?

Is this possible in jQuery and if so how do I implement it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checkout the [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event, and the [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css) method.

Look at the list of [possible selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors) to see how to target your element.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('selectorForYourElement').css('display', 'none');
});
```

### Edit:

To answer your question, you can either combine the selector with the [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector) selector, or use the [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice) method (preferred).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('selectorForYourElement').slice(1).css('display', 'none');
});
```

Or

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('selectorForYourElement:gt(0)').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: Further to this... would it be possible to change all instances of this EXCEPT the first instance?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('selector').css({
    display: 'none'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the block an id f.e. hideMe and do this in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("#hideMe").hide();});
```