# How to update css files at runtime in java application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I have a java spring application. I have to update css files at runtime meaning that from user interface I will select color using color picker when I click on save button I have to update css files with specified color.

I am trying updating css files from location `tomcat7\webapps\<project-name> folder\themes` and so on. But again I need to create war file and needs deployment.

Is there any better way doing it?

Basically, what I need is when I change color from user interface, same color should be applied to whole web application through css.

Comment: Don't you think that a better (correct) approach is to have few versions of these css's which will be the `themes` of your application?

Comment: yea..sounds good. Do you have any reference link for this? also, I will need to check if user is happy with limited number (like 8 or 10) of pre-defined colors css.

Answer (score 0):

If a user needs to select ANY color from a color picker, it probably doesn't make sense using separate style sheets. Instead, you could run JavaScript on the load of each page to set the specific colors. You could pass the values to the web page from your application or call an ajax function to get the style. The JavaScript could be included on every page. This would require keeping a users color/style choice in a persistent location like a database or the user's session.

Something like this [Change CSS value when page has loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516028/change-css-value-when-page-has-loaded). You may want to set the styles before the page is displayed though. (i.e., not in the '.ready' function)